# Java Servlet - ERROR 404 Required resource not found - I can't find the error

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, servlets

I have a web application in JSP. I made a computer change and migrated my eclipse project to the new computer. In the old one I had Tomcat 9, now I have Tomcat 10. I did not make any changes to the code when I sent everything to the new computer.

When I run my application and search for the first servlet, it cannot find it, it sends me an error:

***HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Status report type

message The required resource [/WebProject/LoginServlet] is not available

Description The required resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/10.0.2***

It is worth mentioning that I do not use the implementation descriptor, I use the annotations with the @WebServlet

```
import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

/**
* Servlet implementation class LoginServlet
*/
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@WebServlet("/LoginServlet")
public class LoginServlet extends HttpServlet {
...my content...
}
```

I rewrote a part of the application in another test project because I thought that maybe something would change between version 9 and 10 of Tomcat, however the result is the same. Although it seems that I have to define where it will take the servlets by default when using an annotation, I'm not sure where I can configure that.

Anyone who can help or guide me with this problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.\* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the same problem as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does), although you have different symptoms.

Tomcat implements standards from [Jakarta EE 9](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/9/), which for copyright reasons has a very breaking change: all APIs changed namespace from `javax.*` to `jakarta.*`. You server scans the classpath for `jakarta.servlet.WebServlet` annotations, so it ignores your `javax.servlet.WebServlet` annotation.

You have one of two solutions:

- keep using Tomcat 9: I believe it will be supported for a very long time, as well as all libraries that use the `javax.*` prefix,
- replace in Eclipse the runtime you are coding against with Tomcat's 10 and update the prefixes of the imported classes. There is also a [migration tool](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-migration.cgi) that does it for you.

Comment: This was exactly what I was reading 10 minutes ago. It solved the issue! Many thanks!