# java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets

Having this servlet:

```
public class AddServlet extends HttpServlet {
    public AddServlet() {
    }

    @Override
    public void service(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException {
        int n1 = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num1"));
        int n2 = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("num2"));

        int out = n1 + n2;
        System.out.println("Output: " + out);
    }
}
```

and `index.html`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="add">
        Enter 1st number: <input type="text" name="num1"><br>
        Enter 2nd number: <input type="text" name="num2"><br>
        <button>Submit</button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and using `tomcat 10.0.111`, I got these errors on submit:

```
jakarta.servlet.ServletException: Error instantiating servlet class [com.example.demo.AddServlet]
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1699)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Root Cause

java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:490)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:690)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:353)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:382)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:870)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1699)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

How to solve this?

PS:
the tomcat was added in intellij as `application servers` with base dir in `/opt/apache-tomcat-10.0.11`. Why cannot the servle container (tomcat) initialize the servlet?

Comment: which package is HttpServlet in, and which servlet-API version are you building against?

Comment: Until further notice I assume that you're running into a variation of this problem: [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.\* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does) - e.g. you're expecting javax.servlet.* code, which you'll get up to Tomcat 9.