# The import javax.servlet cannot be resolved STILL

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

Here is my Eclipse-wide JRE definition clearly showing the servlet-api.jar has been added:

[image]

And here are the same old import errors that just never seem to be able to be resolved. Isn't Java awesome? Any chance someone has a simple, factual answer as to why this still doesn't work?

[image]

Comment: The project says it is using JavaSE-11 execution environment - is that set to be using the Java 17?

Comment: Shouldn't you include Tomcat libraries as a normal library instead of a JRE? Sorry haven't used Eclipse in centuries.

Comment: Are you not able to add Tomcat server library onto the build path? Please do try and update - Right-click on project -> Build Path -> Configure Build Path... -> Libraries (tab) -> Select Classpath -> Add Library -> Server Runtime -> Select the one you must have added for Tomcat 10.

Comment: If you haven't set up Tomcat server runtime, then Windows -> Preferences -> Server -> Runtime Environments -> Add.

Comment: You're using the servlet JAR of Tomcat 10, which uses JakartaEE 9, which switched from the `javax.*` package namespace to `jakarta.*` package namespace. Either downgrade to Tomcat 9, or make sure you use the new JakartaEE 9 package names.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## `jakarta.servlet` versus `javax.servlet`

> Any chance someone has a simple, factual answer as to why this still doesn't work?

Because:

- You are building against the Tomcat 10.0.10 servlet-api JAR file.
- Tomcat 10.0.x implements version 5.0 of the Servlet spec; see http://tomcat.apache.org/whichversion.html
- Servlet 5.0 is Jakarta EE, not Java EE; see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jakarta_Servlet#History
- In later versions of Jakarta EE, the package names for the servlet classes have changed from `javax.servlet` to `jakarta.servlet`.

And your code is trying to use the **old** package name.

Solutions:

1. Change your webapp code to import from the **new** `jakarta.servlet`  package, OR
2. Roll back to a version of Tomcat that supports the older version of the Servlet spec; i.e. Tomcat 9.0.x or earlier.