# Tomcat send me the message HTTP Status 404 - Not Found

Tags: java, apache, maven, tomcat, dspace

I'm on windows 10, using tomcat, I stalled dspace, and many libraries [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kxowz.png)
they are located on the folder,dspace\webapps

so acorded to the documentation, point 9 and 10: `https://wiki.lyrasis.org/display/DSDOC6x/Installing+DSpace`

I create a dspace.xml on Tomcat 10.0\conf\Catalina\localhost, that have the next code:

```html
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Context
    docBase="C:/dspace/webapps/xmlui"
    reloadable="true"
    cachingAllowed="false"/>
```

So, when I start Apache Tomcat, and enter to the direction: http://localhost:8080
I have the next view correctly:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOTX8.png)

But if I try to enter to http://localhost:8080/dspace

I have a 404 page, sorry for the language, it must be in spanish.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3D9Gd.png)

That is the problem, I tried to do the option b, copy and paste directly the folders from space to Tomcat webapps, but still having the same error.

I'm thinking thatthere is no problem with Tomcat, because if I add a Root.xml y can not enter to http://localhost:8080, naturally because is empty.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.\* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does) (it doesn't look like this, but the dspace installation instructions list tomcat 7 and 8. You should use Tomcat 8.5 or 9, but likely Tomcat 10 won't work due to the change from JavaEE to JakartaEE.

Answer (score 0):

What you can see from the error message in the browser is that Tomcat itself is running and reachable, however the web application you were trying to reach was not accessible on that URL.

A better view on what is going on is likely in the Tomcat logfiles which you did not publish.

So now I am assuming that nothing went wrong during deployment of the web application. Then I am still wondering whether the URL `http://localhost:8080/dspace` is the correct one to use.

Would you like to try `http://localhost:8080/xmlui`?

Comment: I am still without entering the links:
http://localhost:8080/xmlui
or 
http://localhost:8080/dspace 

I don't know why, I also tried using the dspace.xml or xmlui.xml and copy the files on dspace\webapps and pasted them in Tomcat 10.0\webapps

If could help, I can comment on the logfiles, so you could tell me which one could help.
Thank you for your time!

Comment: It seems you never had a look at the logfiles yourself. Do that, and check https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/introduction.html#Directories_and_Files