# tomcat-embed-core:10.1.0-M16 will make the import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse cannot be resolve

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, tomcat

If I put the latest org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.0-M16 dependecy, it will make the import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse cannot be resolve.

Here's my build.gradle,

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:10.1.0-M16'
}
```

How do I fixed this?

Thank you!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.\* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`tomcat-embed-core:9.0.63` provided by Spring Boot also contained repackaged classes from `javax.servlet-api` library, but they are no longer present in 10.1 branch due to migration from `javax.servlet` to `jakarta.servlet`. You could manually add this dependency to fix the compilation error:

```
compileOnly 'javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:4.0.1'
```

However, this alone won't fix the issue, as Spring Boot 2.7 is just not internally compatible with Tomcat 10.1 because of its migration from `javax.servlet` to Jakarta APIs. If you want to try Tomcat 10.1 with Spring Boot, you'd most probably have to wait until Spring Boot 3 comes out. See more info in [Spring Boot blog](https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/02/a-java-17-and-jakarta-ee-9-baseline-for-spring-framework-6).

Comment: This was suppress with my sonarqube admin...