# Tomcat server cannot find Servlet HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: maven, jsp, tomcat, intellij-idea, servlets

I'm working on a web application project with the Maven build system. This project was created by IntelliJ IDEA. Using full platform dependency. This is the project structure:

[image: Project structure]

The web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd"
         version="4.0">
</web-app>
```

ServletFile:

```
package com.foodsharing;

import java.io.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.*;

@WebServlet(name = "helloServlet", value = "/hello-servlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private String message;

    public void init() {
        message = "Hello World!";
    }

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
        response.setContentType("text/html");

        // Hello
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><body>");
        out.println("<h1>" + message + "</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
    }

    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

JSP file:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>JSP - Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1><%= "Hello World!" %>
</h1>
<br/>
<a href="hello-servlet">Hello Servlet</a>
</body>
</html>
```

And pom file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>food-sharing</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>food-sharing</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <junit.version>5.9.1</junit.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mvc</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.mvc-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.ws</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jws</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.jws-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>11.2.2.jre8</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.2</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I was using the prebuild artifact with the following run configuration:
[image: Run]

[image: Artifact]

When I run, the JSP works fine, but when I click the anchor to servlet, It shows the error:

```
HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message The requested resource [/food_sharing_war_exploded/hello-servlet] is not available

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/10.0.27
```

Please help me with this, if my question is not correct somewhere please correct it.

Comment: Use tomcat9 and read about the difference between version 9 and 10.

Comment: The Tomcat 10 moves from Java EE to Jakarta EE (e.g. from `javax.servlet.http.*;
` import to `jakarta.servlet.http.*;`. You need to use Tomcat 9 to run this project or create a new project again (via `New | Jakarta EE | Next | Version (not choose Java EE 8 in top) to create a project work in Tomcat 10.

Comment: Marking (one of) the duplicate(s): [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.\* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does)

Answer (score 0):

As LJ replica and Olaf Kock pointed out, it seems the problem is that I'm using Tomcat 10, which is not compatible with Java EE. I've change the dependency to "jakarta.servlet" and everything works fine now.