# How to resolve Tomcat filter failed to start error? Tomcat/Maven/IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: maven, tomcat, intellij-idea

I'm able to compile a demo Apache Struts 2.3.30 web app using Maven with Java 17.

When I run Tomcat from IntelliJ IDEA and navigate to the web app, I get a 404 error. I am using the Tomcat Smart Plugin.

The Tomcat console shows "SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start"

I receive "java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter" as an error message in the container logs.

Below are the full container logs, my project's pom.xml file, and the Tomcat console output. The commended out lines in the pom.xml contain what I've tried so far.

Any ideas?

**Full container logs:**

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1012)
        at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2487)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:865)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1401)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1245)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClass(DefaultInstanceManager.java:490)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.loadClassMaybePrivileged(DefaultInstanceManager.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.DefaultInstanceManager.newInstance(DefaultInstanceManager.java:142)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.getFilter(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:243)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterConfig.<init>(ApplicationFilterConfig.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.filterStart(StandardContext.java:4305)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4918)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:683)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:658)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:641)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployDescriptor.run(HostConfig.java:1927)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:534)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1656)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:366)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:898)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:846)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:241)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:913)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:795)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.Filter
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1437)
        at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1245)
        ... 53 more
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
/*
 * $Id$
 *
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *  http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
 * software distributed under the License is distributed on an
 * "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
 * KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
 * specific language governing permissions and limitations
 * under the License.
 */
-->
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts2-apps</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.30</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>struts2-rest-showcase</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>2.3.30</version>
    <name>Struts 2 Rest Showcase Webapp</name>
    <description>Struts 2 Rest Showcase Example</description>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-rest-plugin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-convention-plugin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
            <artifactId>struts2-config-browser-plugin</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>${log4j2.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jwebunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwebunit-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jwebunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>jwebunit-htmlunit-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>xom</groupId>
                    <artifactId>xom</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        -->

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>struts2-rest-showcase</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <!--
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
                <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin-test</artifactId>
                <version>8.1.16.v20140903</version>
                <configuration>
                    <stopKey>CTRL+C</stopKey>
                    <stopPort>8999</stopPort>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <systemProperty>
                            <name>xwork.loggerFactory</name>
                            <value>com.opensymphony.xwork2.util.logging.log4j2.Log4j2LoggerFactory</value>
                        </systemProperty>
                    </systemProperties>
                    <scanIntervalSeconds>10</scanIntervalSeconds>
                    <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/</webAppSourceDirectory>
                    <webAppConfig>
                        <contextPath>/struts2-rest-showcase</contextPath>
                        <descriptor>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</descriptor>
                    </webAppConfig>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            -->
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>17</source>
                    <target>17</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>it/**</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/*$*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3.1</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>17</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>17</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
</project>
```

**Tomcat Console Output**

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin\java.exe" "-Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1" -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\jsowe\.SmartTomcat\rest-demo\struts2-rest-showcase -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\jsowe\.SmartTomcat\rest-demo\struts2-rest-showcase\temp -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\jsowe\.SmartTomcat\rest-demo\struts2-rest-showcase\conf\logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=51958:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\bin\bootstrap.jar;C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1\bin\tomcat-juli.jar" org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap start
NOTE: Picked up JDK_JAVA_OPTIONS: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
18-May-2023 15:49:42.300 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.1.8
18-May-2023 15:49:42.303 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Apr 14 2023 19:40:29 UTC
18-May-2023 15:49:42.303 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 10.1.8.0
18-May-2023 15:49:42.303 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 11
18-May-2023 15:49:42.304 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
18-May-2023 15:49:42.304 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
18-May-2023 15:49:42.304 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17
18-May-2023 15:49:42.304 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           17.0.7+8-LTS-224
18-May-2023 15:49:42.304 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
18-May-2023 15:49:42.304 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\jsowe\.SmartTomcat\rest-demo\struts2-rest-showcase
18-May-2023 15:49:42.304 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1
18-May-2023 15:49:42.309 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
18-May-2023 15:49:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
18-May-2023 15:49:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
18-May-2023 15:49:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
18-May-2023 15:49:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
18-May-2023 15:49:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 10.1
18-May-2023 15:49:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\jsowe\.SmartTomcat\rest-demo\struts2-rest-showcase
18-May-2023 15:49:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\Users\jsowe\.SmartTomcat\rest-demo\struts2-rest-showcase\temp
18-May-2023 15:49:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\Users\jsowe\.SmartTomcat\rest-demo\struts2-rest-showcase\conf\logging.properties
18-May-2023 15:49:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
18-May-2023 15:49:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\lib\idea_rt.jar=51958:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\bin
18-May-2023 15:49:42.310 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
18-May-2023 15:49:42.313 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.lifecycleEvent The Apache Tomcat Native library which allows using OpenSSL was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Users\jsowe\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;;C:\Users\jsowe\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2023.1.2\bin;;.]
18-May-2023 15:49:42.509 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-May-2023 15:49:42.533 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [364] milliseconds
18-May-2023 15:49:42.573 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
18-May-2023 15:49:42.574 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/10.1.8]
18-May-2023 15:49:42.586 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deploying deployment descriptor [C:\Users\jsowe\.SmartTomcat\rest-demo\struts2-rest-showcase\conf\Catalina\localhost\struts2-rest-showcase.xml]
18-May-2023 15:49:43.386 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
18-May-2023 15:49:43.440 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more Filters failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
18-May-2023 15:49:43.440 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/struts2-rest-showcase] startup failed due to previous errors
18-May-2023 15:49:43.448 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor Deployment of deployment descriptor [C:\Users\jsowe\.SmartTomcat\rest-demo\struts2-rest-showcase\conf\Catalina\localhost\struts2-rest-showcase.xml] has finished in [861] ms
18-May-2023 15:49:43.450 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.start Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-May-2023 15:49:43.484 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start Server startup in [950] milliseconds
http://localhost:8080/struts2-rest-showcase
18-May-2023 15:57:00.233 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-May-2023 15:57:00.236 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service [Catalina]
18-May-2023 15:57:00.236 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
18-May-2023 15:57:00.249 INFO [Thread-1] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]

Process finished with exit code 130
```

Comment: You are using Tomcat 10.1 (`version name:   Apache Tomcat/10.1.8`), and getting the error `NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/Filter`. That version of Tomcat no longer uses the `javax` namespace. See [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-10.cgi): "_Users of Tomcat 10 onwards should be aware that, as a result of the move from Java EE to Jakarta EE as part of the transfer of Java EE to the Eclipse Foundation, the primary package for all implemented APIs has changed from javax.* to jakarta.*. This will almost certainly require code changes..._"

Comment: A write-up: [Transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee). Does this answer your question? [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.\* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does)