# How do I remove HTTP Servlet cannot be resolved to a type, in my web app project

Tags: java, eclipse, macos, tomcat, web-applications

I am a beginner when it comes to dynamic web projects so far I have setup a web project.

The guide I am [following(https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-build-a-web-application-using-java)a guide.

It says to remove all the errors I should add the Servlet Jar file.

I have done that but my eclipse only lets me add it to either "module path" or "class path" I was able to add it to both but it wouldn't let me "apply and close".

When I add it to only class path or module path the errors of my project remain.

I am using apache-tomcat-10.1.15
java version 21.0.1

[build path, servlet jar file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u3SfS.png)

```
 */
@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

/**
 * Default constructor. 
 */
public TestServlet() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
}

/**
 * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
 */
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    doGet(request, response);
}

}
```

All tutorials that I have watched that fix this problem don't have "class path" and "module path" so it fixes the problem for them, but it doesn't fix the problem for me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Servlet 5.0 JAR throws compile error on javax.servlet.\* but Servlet 4.0 JAR does not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64387472/servlet-5-0-jar-throws-compile-error-on-javax-servlet-but-servlet-4-0-jar-does)

Comment: Please [don't upload text as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13447). Edit your question to contain all the information in text form - consider to use the editor's formatting options. Also see [ask]. For this problem: Use Tomcat 9, or `jakarta.servlet` classes

Answer (score 1):

Mainly it looks like you have no `import` statement for the `HttpServlet` type. On a line where the error message appears, tap Ctrl+1 (or Cmd+1 on a Mac) and let it add one for you.

You've listed the Tomcat and Java versions, what about the *Eclipse* version?

As someone who's worked on these server tools, that tutorial is not a good one. You should be getting the Servlet API to build against from an actual server, just as you get the Java standard libraries to build against from a real JDK/JRE. Add the Tomcat runtime to the **Servers**/**Runtime Environments** preference page, then in the **Build Path** properties page's **Libraries** tab, add a **Server Runtime** library referring to it, and then remove that manually added servet API jar.